# C# MWS "the Content-MD5 HTTP header you passed for your feed did not match the Content-MD5 we calculated for your feed"

Tags: c#, e-commerce, amazon-mws

I am trying to consume Amazon Feeds API > SubmitFeed operation.

I set request's FeedContent a memory stream created by XmlWriter.

Request's ContentMD5 variable is set with:

```
 request.ContentMD5 = MarketplaceWebServiceClient.CalculateContentMD5(request.FeedContent);
```

I am using Amazon MWS Feeds Api Client Library (https://developer.amazonservices.com/doc/bde/feeds/v20090101/cSharp.html)

I didn't change the codes. When I call MarketplaceWebService.SubmitFeed , I get this error:

"the Content-MD5 HTTP header you passed for your feed did not match the Content-MD5 we calculated for your feed"

Amazon says that: their calculated MD5 and my MD5 values are different. Why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

I added Amazon Feeds Api Client Library > MarketplaceWebServiceClient.cs file a method:

```
 public static string CalculateContentMD5(byte[] content)
 {
        MD5CryptoServiceProvider provider = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
        byte[] hash = provider.ComputeHash(content);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
 }
```

There is a

```
public static string CalculateContentMD5(Stream content)
```

function, but it doesnt't work properly.

Use byte[] instead of Stream to calculate MD5 hash.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your own answer, ensure you are setting the stream position back to zero before calculating the hash. This should solve your problem:

```
public static string CalculateContentMD5(Stream stream)
{
    stream.Position = 0;
    MD5CryptoServiceProvider provider = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
    byte[] hash = provider.ComputeHash(content);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
}
```